# Got invalid value from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am getting invalid value in `ListView`. My code is below.

```
 final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> placesListItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dealList.size(); i++) {
                        map.put(DealItem.DEAL_ID, dealList.get(i).deal_id);
                        map.put(DealItem.DEAL_NAME, dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                        System.out.println("DEAL NAME = "+dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                        placesListItems.add(map);

                    }

                    new PlacesMapActivity(SinglePlaceActivity.this, lon, lat, name, add);

                    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(SinglePlaceActivity.this, placesListItems, R.layout.list_item_deal, new String[] {
                            DealItem.DEAL_ID, DealItem.DEAL_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.reference, R.id.name });
                    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

when i run this code i am getting answer like this

```
  10-03 18:37:29.429: I/System.out(3957): DEAL NAME = Sinbad Cafe
  10-03 18:37:52.369: I/System.out(3957): DEAL NAME = Coffee,Tea, Hot Milk
  10-03 18:37:55.189: I/System.out(3957): DEAL NAME = Httpss
```

But I do not understand why I am getting an invalid value in `ListView`

Like below:

```
  Httpss
  Httpss
  Httpss
```

Comment: @Shark : simpleAdapter is *made* for list of maps. how is it amazing?

Comment: whoops, my bad. thought it was more like BaseAdapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   +-------- HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   |
   |            for (int i = 0; i < dealList.size(); i++) {
   +--------------->  
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_ID, dealList.get(i).deal_id);
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_NAME, dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    System.out.println("DEAL NAME = "+dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    placesListItems.add(map);

                }
```

Since you have your "HashMap" initialization outside your loop, you are actually overwriting the same hashmap and putting it back to the arraylist..

Try to **move your HashMap initialization** inside for-loop..

Answer (score 1):

The same map is added to the list several times.

Try moving the new HashMap<...>-line into the for-loop:

```
                for (int i = 0; i < dealList.size(); i++) {
         -->        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_ID, dealList.get(i).deal_id);
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_NAME, dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    System.out.println("DEAL NAME = "+dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    placesListItems.add(map);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

change code with following code it will solve your error.....

```
    try {


                for (int i = 0; i < dealList.size(); i++) {
                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_ID, dealList.get(i).deal_id);
                    map.put(DealItem.DEAL_NAME, dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    System.out.println("DEAL NAME = "+dealList.get(i).deal_name);
                    placesListItems.add(map);

      }
```